# NSRegularExpression matches error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

I use `NSRegularExpression` to decompress a string. transfer @"A" to @",-1" and @"B" to @",-2" to decompress it.

The problem is if only apply `@"A" to @",-1" or @"B" to @",-2"` separately, it works ok. but when apply both in a for loop, I found that `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock` doesn't find matches when search `@"B"`.
Any ideas?

```
NSString *compressed = @"[303b18c01a,Ac24a6,Aa6,,Ah,A,a1,,,a8,b,c5,aad,bcg,dha9,fa4a7,ib4a9,da4a5,ca1a6,aha7,aea6,,aa6,BCa8,]";
NSMutableString *compressedCopy = [compressed mutableCopy];

//the array contains two patterns
NSArray *regulars = @[[self regexO:@"A" n:@",-1"],
                      [self regexO:@"B" n:@",-2"]];

NSInteger count = [regulars count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *regexInfo = regulars[i];
        NSString *old = regexInfo[REGEX_OLD_KEY];
        NSString *new = regexInfo[REGEX_NEW_KEY];

        NSString *origin = [compressedCopy copy];

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:old options:0 error:nil];

        if (regex) {
            __block int offset = 0;
            [regex enumerateMatchesInString:origin options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [compressed length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                NSRange range = [result range];
                range.location += offset;
                [compressedCopy replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:new];
                offset += [new length] - [old length];
            }];
    }
```

followed is to save the pattern

```
- (NSDictionary *)regexO:(NSString *)old n:(NSString *)new
{
    NSDictionary *regex = @{REGEX_OLD_KEY: old, REGEX_NEW_KEY: new};
    return regex;
}
```

--------------------------to make it more clear-------------------------

the origin data is array which contains many points coordinates, such as:

```
[131,61,648,1,1,-1,0]
```

the compressed data that I need handle is like -> NSString *compressed.

the algorithm of decompress is to change the character in compressed string, such as change "A" to @",-1".

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do.  You say "compressing" but it don't see how.  Also using regular expressions seems over-the-top; why not just enumerate the characters, check their range and then apply the tranformation using normal code?

Comment: cause it's only the parts of the data, whole data is really big. so it's poor performance if using NSString related.

Answer (score 0):

finally find out it's a stupid mistake. the range that pass to the method is wrong so it cannot generate proper result.

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:origin options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [origin length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
```